# Regex: How to get rid of trailing newline symbol in the match?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I was looking for a regular expression that will match the first date that is NOT followed by a line that stars with 'R' letter (I want to get last commit date from `git log`, *except* for only path changing commits).

```
2021-12-07T16:39:43+01:00
M       test.md

2021-12-07T16:18:59+01:00
R100    old.test.md  test.md

2021-12-07T15:37:15+01:00
A       old.test.md
```

After a significant struggle, I get this regex (I don't care much about the date validity, I trust Git):

```
/20[\d-T:.Z+]+(?:\r?\n)(?!R)/
```

It is working quite fine – but it leaves a trailing newline character `\n`. No big deal, it can be repaced; but safely chaining `match` with `replace` makes the code incredibly ugly (I am using Node.js):

```
import { execSync } from "child_process"

const allAuthorDates = execSync(
  `git log --follow --name-status --pretty=format:%aI -- test.md`
).toString()

const lastEditExceptPathChangeDateMatch = allAuthorDates.match(
  /20[\d-T:.Z+]+(?:\r?\n)(?!R)/
)

console.log(lastEditExceptPathChangeDateMatch)

/*
[
  '2021-12-07T16:39:43+01:00\n', <-- how to get rid of that \n?
  index: 0,
  input: '2021-12-07T16:39:43+01:00\nA\ttest.md\n',
  groups: undefined
]
*/
```

Because of the trailing newline char, I am forced to use the horrible `let result = (str.match(/…/) || [""])[0].replace(…)` is there to prevent the runtime error in (probably unlikely) case the match will return `null`.

Would somebody be so kind to advice me how to edit the regex to get rid of the trailing `\n`  while matching, to make the following `replace` unneccessary?

Comment: Move it to the lookahead, `/20[\d-T:.Z+]+$(?!\r?\nR)/m`, or even `/^20\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}$(?!\r?\nR)/gm`

Comment: This isn't really a Git question, unless you're looking for some way to have Git not produce the newline there (and unfortunately there isn't one). I'm going to snip the [tag:git] tag. Newlines in regex tend to depend on the regex engine, specifically whether it allows matching more than one line including newlines; I don't know about js here. A third way to do this, of course, is a bit of post-processing to remove the newlines entirely, before doing the regex matching. :-)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew thanks, it works like a charm. The `$` symbol is matching the end of a line here?

Comment: @torek Fair enough, not really Git related. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the end of the line with `$` (making sure you add the `m` flag) and then use the negative lookahead with the `\r?\n` pattern moved into the lookahead right before `R`:

```js
/20[\d-T:.Z+]+$(?!\r?\nR)/m
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bUMuD1/2). Or, if you want to spell out the pattern:

```js
/^20\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}$(?!\r?\nR)/gm
```

Here, I also added `g` flag to match multiple occurrences. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bUMuD1/1).

The `$(?!\r?\nR)` part matches the position before CR or LF char (carriage return or line feed) and then makes sure there is no optional CR char, an LF char and `R` immediately to the right of the current location.